# Python referencing instance list variable

Tags: python

I just started to learn Python and I"m struggling a little with instance variables.  So I create an instance variable in a method that's of a list type.  Later on, I want to call and display that variable's contents. However, I'm having issues doing that. I read some online, but I still can't get it to work.  I was thinking of something along the following (this is a simplified version):
What would the proper way of doing this be?

```
    class A:
        def _init_(self):
            self.listVar = [B("1","2","3"), B("1","2","3")]
        def setListVal():
            #Is this needed? Likewise a "get" method"?
        def randomMethod():
            A.listVar[0] #something like that to call/display it right? Or would a for  
                         #for loop style command be needed?

     Class B:
        def _init_(self):
            self.a = ""
            self.b = ""
            self.c = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the list something you'll be passing to the instance when you create it (i.e. will it be different each time)?

If so, try this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.listVar = list
```

Now, when you instantiate (read: create an instance) of a class, you can pass a list to it and it will be saved as the `listVar` attribute for that instance.

Example:

```
>>> first_list = [B("1","2","3"), B("1","2","3")]
>>> second_list = [C("1","2","3"), C("1","2","3")]
>>> first_instance = A(first_list)  # Create your first instance and pass it your first_list. Assign it to variable first_instance
>>> first_instance.listVar  # Ask for the listVar attribute of your first_instance
[B("1","2","3"), B("1","2","3")]  # Receive the list you passed
>>> second_instance = A(second_list)  # Create your second instance and pass it your second_list. Assign it to variable second_instance
>>> second_instance.listVar  # Ask for the listVar attribute of your second_instance
[C("1","2","3"), C("1","2","3")]  # Receive the list you passed second instance
```

Feel free to ask if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listVar = [B("1","2","3"), B("1","2","3")]
    def setListVal(self, val):
        self.listVar[0] = val # example of changing the first entry
    def randomMethod(self):
        print self.listVar[0].a  # prints 'a' from the first entry in the list

class B:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

I made several changes. You need to use `self` as the first argument to all the methods. That argument is the way that you reference all the instance variables. The initialization function is `__init__` note that is 2 underscores before and after.  You are passing three arguments to initialize `B`, so you need to have 3 arguments in addition to self.